# Apache Beam typecoders errors and fallback on typehint - GCP Dataflow tutorial

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow, google-cloud-platform

While trying to do the GCP "[Simple dataflow pipeline (Python)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb101-simple-dataflow-py/#0)" codelab, I got stuck in a very weird error.

As a heads-up, I am not running on my localmachine. I create a new cloudshell instance on GCP with a clean slate and just clone the repo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst.

I am trying to run on the local machine `python ~/training-data-analyst/courses/data_analysis/lab2/python/grep.py` as the `grepc.py` is the one to run on GCP Dataflow itself.

I get the following error (the same happens when trying to run `grepc.py`:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file" 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:135: UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: <type 'NoneType'>. 
warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
```

Any ideas about this?